# Undertow (JBoss 7) mangles / re-encodes URL-encoded parameter on redirect

Tags: servlets, jboss, jboss7.x, undertow, jboss-eap-7

Posted in JBoss forums as well:
https://developer.jboss.org/thread/280195

**update 2019-06-26** apparently this is now confirmed as a bug in Undertow, with a pull request submitted [here](https://issues.jboss.org/projects/UNDERTOW/issues/UNDERTOW-1565).

This is a SSCCE.

I have a very simple Servlet that does nothing except print the value of a parameter:

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet{
    public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String URL = req.getParameter("url");
        System.out.printf("url parameter read as: [%s]\n", URL);
    }
}
```

My application's web.xml is configured so as to automatically redirect `http` access to `https`:

```
<web-app>
 ...
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>SECURE</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

… and I also have (in my `standalone-full.xml` configuration file) the `redirect-socket` attribute set in the definition of the `http-listener`:

```
<http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
```

If I deploy to JBoss EAP 7.1 and enter the following URL in my browser (where the `url` parameter carries the URL-encoded value of "http://www.google.com"):

```
http://localhost:8082/get-parameter-test/min?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com
```

… this is what I see in the developer console:

[image]

As a result, after the automatic redirect, my code fails to obtain the correct value of the `url` parameter and I see in the log files:

```
url parameter read as: [http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com]
```

However, if I deploy to JBoss EAP 6.2 and do the same, the URL is not mangled in the redirect and everything works fine:

[image]

## update

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56520787/274677) suggests that the `decode-url` parameter in the configuration of the `http-listener` and `https-listener` in the undertow system in the JBoss configuration file (`standalong-full.xml`) may have something to do with this. This is wrong. I tried all four combinations:

- http-listener: `decode-url`="false" and https-listener: `decode-url`="false"
- http-listener: `decode-url`="false" and https-listener: `decode-url`="true"
- http-listener: `decode-url`="true" and https-listener: `decode-url`="false"
- http-listener: `decode-url`="true" and https-listener: `decode-url`="true"

In all cases, the 302 response that's effecting the redirect from http to https has the following header:

`Location: https://localhost:8445/get-parameter-test?url=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com`

That is in all cases, the URL is mangled (call it re-encoded it if you like, it's mangled AFAIAC). There's no reason for this behavior at all and it is not what EAP 6.2 does. The value of the `decode-url` parameter only affects the behavior of the `HttpServletRequest#getRequest` method inside your servlet, it has no effect whatsoever in the redirected URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **update 2019-06-26** Apparently this is now confirmed as a bug in
>   Undertow, with a pull request submitted [here](https://issues.jboss.org/projects/UNDERTOW/issues/UNDERTOW-1565)

Here's what ultimately worked for me.
First of all, I removed from my `web.xml` the entire `<security-constraint>` element as it is not needed for the solution I implemented.
I also removed the `redirect-socket="https"` from the `<http-listener>` configuration. That too, is also not needed. So here's what my `<http-listener>` and `<https-listener>` look like:

```
<http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" enable-http2="true"/>
<https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
```

I think the above is exactly what you get in JBoss EAP 7.1 out of the box, so no need to change that.

I then created a filter and added it in the `<filters>` element of the *undertow* subsystem:

```
<rewrite name="http-to-https" redirect="true" target="https://%h:8445%U%q"/>
```

- `%h` is the remote host name
- `%U` is the requested URL path
- `%q` is the query string (automatically prepended with `?` if it exists)

I found the above codes [here](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/2.1.x/config/valve.html) - I am sure there's a more normative reference somewhere else but they seem to work.

Finally, I added a reference to the filter, along with a predicate, in the `<server>/<host>` element (also in the *undertow* subsystem):

```
<server name="default-server">
    <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" enable-http2="true"/>
    <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
    <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
        <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
        <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
        <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
        <filter-ref name="http-to-https" predicate="equals(%p, 8082)"/>
        <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
    </host>
</server>
```

With the above configuration the request gets redirected without re-encoding the URL:

```
$ curl -I -L -k http://localhost:8082/get-parameter-test?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Connection: keep-alive
Server: JBoss-EAP/7
Location: https://127.0.0.1:8445/get-parameter-test?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 11 Jun 2019 17:43:23 GMT

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Undertow/1
Server: JBoss-EAP/7
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 11 Jun 2019 17:43:23 GMT
```

… and the parameter is correctly read from Java:

```
url parameter read as: [http://www.google.com]
```

There is no need to set `decode-url="true"` in the http/https listeners as that's the default value.

**NB: The above causes JBoss EAP 7.1 to send a 302 redirect. I have no idea how to configure a 303 or 307 redirect.**

### Final remark

The obvious alternative to the above is to do the redirect programmatically from your application's code using [HttpServletRequest#sendRedirect](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect-java.lang.String-). In that case too, you do **not** need `redirect-socket="https"` in your `http-listener`.

Apparently, the `redirect-socket` attribute is only necessary in conjunction with the `<security-constraint>` element in your application's *web.xml*. That's because otherwise (i.e. if you have the `<security-constraint>` in your `web.xml` but no `redirect-socket` in your `http-listener`), you get hit with:

`ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-14) UT005001: An exception occurred processing the request: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT010053: No confidential port is available to redirect the current request.`).

However if you have both the `<security-constraint>` and the `redirect-socket`, the query String is needlessly re-URL-encoded (and thus mangled) in the redirected URL as explained in the question. So it's not clear to me what's the use of `<security-constraint>` in JBoss EAP 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

You are URL is not getting mangled its getting re-encoded. The issue is of re-encoding or URL while redirecting from http to https. You are passing encoded url parameter to `http` i.e. http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.

```
http://www.google.com --encode--> http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com --re-encode--> http%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com
```

In you re-encode url, '%' is getting encoded to '%25'.

To disable this behaviour, you need to make changes in your listners. There is one attribute called **decode-url** which can be used to disable/enable this behaviour.

> `decode-url` :    If the URL should be decoded. If this is not set to
>   true then percent encoded characters in the URL will be left as is.

Refer following link for more information on Undertow subsystem.
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/Undertow+subsystem+configuration

**Note**: This functionality may have worked on JBoss 6.2 because in JBoss 6.2 subsystem for this configuration is called WEB which is replaced by Undertow in JBoss EAP 7+